# '0' Item when using RE and Naming in express with route

Tags: node.js, express, router

I'm trying to split up the following URL (they are no limits to the subquery):

> www.zookeeper.com/api/zoo/monkey/1/feed

into:

```
{
  "Main": "zoo",
   "Sub": "/monkey/1/feed"
}
```

In the following code, the last character is always missing in the *SUB_REQUEST* field.

```
router.get("/:BASE_REQUEST/*:SUB_REQUEST",function(req,res)
{
    res.json(
    {
        "Main":req.params.BASE_REQUEST,                  
        "Sub":req.params.SUB_REQUEST+req.params[0]//append last char hack! 
     });
});
```

If you look at the req.params, there is always a mysterious '0'.

```
{ 
   '0': 'd',
   BASE_REQUEST: 'zoo',
   SUB_REQUEST: '/monkey/1/fee' 
}
```

Could someone please explain this behavior? Where is heck is this '0' coming from?

I'm using express version 4.12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the thing that's happening here is that your route is actually picking out 3 route params, where you think they're picking out 2.

If you try doing `console.log(req.params);` in your route handler, you'll see that a request to `/bob/is/your/uncle` will result in the following object:

`{ '0': 'is/your/uncl', BASE_REQUEST: 'bob', SUB_REQUEST: 'e' }`

That's because you've named two params, and have the unnamed wildcard in there as well, which express defaults to the name '0'.  The third param has to consume at least one part of the route, so it's grabbing the last letter.  I'm not sure why your machine seems to be reversing SUB and 0, unless you're mistaken in how you wrote up the question.

If you just get rid of `:SUB_REQUEST`, it should work the way you want, you just have to refer to the wildcard bit via `req.params.0` (or `req.params['0']`).  There used to be the ability to have a named wildcard param, in previous versions of Express, but I can't find that in the docs anymore so I expect they did away with it to make other things work better.

Comment: thx! I've checked the output again, is exactly like i wrote in my question.

Comment: Regardless, if you remove the third param you should be able to get what you're looking for. Have you tried that?